# Is it ok to use property syntax for no-args methods?

Tags: objective-c, syntax, properties

Lets say a class has a plain old no-args method declared like this:

```
- (NSString *)responseString;
```

There are two ways to call this method. Either using

```
string = [instance responseString];
```

or, with the dot syntax, like this:

```
string = instance.responseString;
```

**What is the preferred way? Any reasons to avoid the last approach?**

---

**Update:**
`responseString` *is* a property of the class, except it is not declared with @property. It is, by definition, an accessor method (getter). The generated code is exactly the same.

(We assume objc v2.0+ here.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My preferred way is always to use the former because I think dot notation is an abomination that should never have been added to the language.

Putting aside my (justified) prejudice for a moment, you should only use dot notation for things that are **conceptually** properties (i.e. they don't necessarily have to use `@property` to declare them but they should be attributes of the object as opposed to operations the object performs). The name of the method in this case is a noun, so the chances are that `-responseString` is a property and it's OK to use dot notation.

An example of something it would not be appropriate to use dot notation for is `NSMutableArray`'s `-removeAllObjects` method.

NB:  regardless of whether you use dot notation or not, it is a good idea to always use `@property` to declare things that are conceptually properties.

Comment: FWIW, apart from nouns for most properties, you can also have boolean properties like `.selected` or `.compressed` that are not nouns.

Comment: @JeremyP: I'm marking this as correct as it seems the most reasonable. I haven't found anything in apples docs that contradicts it at least.

Answer (score 1):

It is a question of attitude, but my preferred way is to use the dot notation for all properties where no mixing is required.

• Use the dot syntax where it makes sense (only properties)

• Use it as often as possible when no mixing is required

Example of mixing:

```
NSString *description = [array objectAtIndex:i].description; // Use [[array objectAtIndex:i] description] instead
```

Answer (score 1):

The first and foremost reason to avoid this type of Dot Syntax usage is that ***it is strongly discouraged by Apple itself***, and may lead to crash or undesired result if used wrongly.

Read through the section *"Incorrect Use of Dot Syntax"* in ["Dot Syntax"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW17)(from Apple's Doc). There listed the different usages of Dot Syntax which are strongly discouraged.

It clearly states that, *"Those code patterns are strongly discouraged because they do not conform to the intended use of dot syntax, namely for invoking an accessor method."*

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how that applies here? `responseString` is an accessor method for a (conceptual) string property calculated on the fly with no side-effects.

Comment: @Martin Wickman, I think you don't understand the doc. You example and doc example are similar.

Comment: @Martin Wickman, `responseString` is a method like `lockFocusIfCanDraw` in Doc, no matter you call it as `conceptual accessor method` or whatever you like.

Comment: @Martin Wickman, What do you mean by a conceptual string property?

Comment: responseString fits the mental concept of a property (like color of a car), except it's not generated with @property. lockFocusIfCanDraw, otoh, is **not** a property in any sense. It is a method with with side effects (a verb btw) and the returned boolean is the result from that action, not the value of the "property". That is the difference and also my interpretation of the docs: "don't treat methods like lockFocusIfCanDraw as properties, because it is not a property in any sense". So I think your answer is wrong.

Comment: If the guideline was stated simply as "Only use dot-notation when accessing methods that are generated from @property", then I'd agree with you.

Comment: You can't code mental concepts in programming languages. You still don't understand what a method is. Even though your method contains single line like `return someOtherProperty;`, that is a method. If you create declared properties, compiler will create getter and setter methods for the property. Both getters and setters are methods only.

Comment: Accessing a property using dot syntax will invoke the getter/setter methods only. So the doc says that properties are allowed to access their getter/setters using dot syntax and not to use the dot syntax to call normal methods(not a getter or setter).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3062/discussion-between-martin-wickman-and-emptystack)

Comment: @EmptyStack:  Martin is correct.  I think it is you that has a misunderstanding.

Comment: @EmptyStack:  Because he is.You are failing to understand the difference between the concept of property and one implementation of it.

Comment: Alright. Lets take an example. If I have a method named `- (void)color`, and that is not a property. So you say that calling `self.color` is correct. Right? And, Martin tells that is correct.